# Possible to spoof iPad UA in Safari through script?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, safari-extension

I apologize if this question comes across as asinine, but is it possible to spoof the UA string of an iPad in Safari via a script of some sort?

I know it can be done through the Develop > User Agent menu item, but I am interested in making a Safari extension that forces a page that only serves HTML5 video to iPads to work without manually changing the UA every time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works on iOS, but [this article might help you](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090630112653430). Some of the comments are useful:

> defaults write com.apple.Safari
>   CustomUserAgent "\"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en)
>   AppleWebKit/419 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Safari/419.3\""

Comment: Thanks! Definitely a step in the right direction.  The only thing I'm not sure of is whether or not Apple would be too keen on an extension modifying Safari's .plist file.

Comment: @user496230 Doubt they would like it (since it would reduce the ratings of iPads in web stats for one thing) but UA strings are not the be-all and end-all of identifiers. Servers should use accept headers to determine what they can and should send to the client. Go right ahead and see what happens.

Comment: Looking into it right now.  Specifically, the site I am trying to "trick" is Flickr.  Going through their source to see if anything pops out.

Comment: I've gotta go now, but I hope this answers your question. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... it's definitely possible!

The UA is just something the browser is sending (and can always be spoofed!)... with a little customization it can be changed, so a browser extension would naturally be able to do that.